# how to remove rows in dataframe with the same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
            c1        c2       c3           c4              c5          c6  
0           abc      lose     Cookie      20190408          13          3   
1           def       win     Cookie      20190413           4          8
2           ghi      lose     Cookie      20190128          13          3
3           def       win     Cookie      20190402          10         -9
```

I got the original data frame above. how to delete all of the row that is called def in column 'c1'
I have tried using `df.drop()` but it does not allow me to specify the value for the column

expected output

```
                 c1        c2       c3           c4              c5          c6  
     0           abc      lose     Cookie      20190408          13          3   
     2           ghi      lose     Cookie      20190128          13          3
```

Comment: df =df .loc[df.c1!='def']

Comment: Read more here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: If there's other values in c1 say... you had two rows with values of `xyz` and you also wanted those dropped if not unique... then you might also want to look at something like: `df.drop_duplicates(subset='c1', keep=False)`

Answer (score 0):

```
   out = df[df["c1"].str.contains("def") == False]
```

Output:

```
    c1    c2      c3        c4  c5  c6
0  abc  lose  Cookie  20190408  13   3
2  ghi  lose  Cookie  20190128  13   3
```